# Showing that $\mathbb{C}^5/\ker(P)\simeq \mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, notation, linear-transformations

Consider the vector space $\mathbb{C}^5$ and the map
$P:\mathbb{C}^5\mapsto\mathbb{C}^5,\,P(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)=(x_1,x_2,0,0,0)$
According to my lecture notes, this implies: $\mathbb{C}^5/\ker(P)\simeq \mathbb{C}^2$. But what exactly does this mean? That $\mathbb{C}^5\ni x\mapsto \mathbb{C}^5/\ker(P)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a vector space $V$ and a subspace $U$ the quotient $V/U$ is defined as the set of equivalence classes of $v\sim w\iff v-w\in U$ equipped with  the inherited operations. You can show that these are well-defined and $V/U$ is in fact a vector space itself. Elements of $V/U$ are commonly written as $[v]:=v+U$.

In your case $V=\Bbb C^5$ and $U=\ker P$ where $P$ is the projection 
$$P\colon\Bbb C^5\to\Bbb C^5,\,(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4,z_5)\mapsto(z_1,z_2,0,0,0)$$
The kernel of $P$ is readily identified with $\Bbb C^3$. The isomorphism theorem (or also called [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) in case of vector spaces) yields that ${\rm im}\,P=\Bbb C^2$ and the desired isomorphism $\Bbb C^5/\ker P\cong\Bbb C^2$.

Comment: I got to the conclusion that $\operatorname{ker} P=\left\{\left(0,0, x_{3}, x_{4}, x_{5}\right): x_{3}, x_{4}, x_{5} \in \mathbb{C}\right\}$. If you say that this can be identified with $\mathbb{C}^3$, does that mean that the projection is also $P : \mathbb{C}^5\mapsto \mathbb{C}^2$?

Comment: @Jacob You can write down an explicit isomorphism $\ker P\to\Bbb C^3$ by sending the $5$-tuple $(0,0,x_3,x_4,x_5)$ to the $3$-tuple $(x_3,x_4,x_5)$. That's what I meant by 'identify'. Technically, the projection is valued in $\Bbb C^5$ but the *image* is isomorphic ot $\Bbb C^2$ in the same sense as the kernel is isomorphic to $\Bbb C^3$. Are you familiar with what I called the *rank-nullity theorem*?

Comment: Ah, right. Yes, I do know the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: @Jacob Good; otherwise my answer might've been a littte over the top :D Glad to help!